# gparted shows unknown system file on nvme ssd

Tags: ubuntu, gparted, nvme, dualboot

I have 3 disks in my system --ACHI MODE--

1.sata ssd 256mb(windows 10 installed on it).

2.hdd 1tb for storage

3.m.2 nvme ssd kingston A2000 500gb(has mostly games in it,steamlibrary)

So i wanted to install ubuntu in the nvme drive and make dual boot without losing my existing data on it.I went through the disk management in windows, i srinked it at about half the space, downloaded ubuntu made rufus etc but when i chose something else,gparted shows the whole nvme drive as unknown file system with no partitions on it.It did the same thing when i manually created a ntfs partition from windows.

I remember i had problems with this nvme drive before, i could not make this drive bootable with windows. Windows installed just fine, bios recognized fine but i just could not boot. So i kept it as a game storage drive

Do u have any ideas?

Mobo is b450 tomahawk

Update: I saw somewhere that changing from csm to eufi mode in bios should fix many things. So i changed it but i cant boot into windows now.Reverting back to csm everything is normal. Windows disk is gpt, i double checked.

!https://ibb.co/Vvx6SVs

!https://ibb.co/j6V2Mn3

!https://ibb.co/34wQ4s2

!https://ibb.co/g7sTJfb

Comment: If Windows disk would be GPT, it would be bootable _only_ in UEFI mode. If it's bootable in CSM, then the disk must be MBR, not GPT. Anyway, boot mode shouldn't affect how partitions are detected. Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: just upload some photos of the problems i've encounter. Sorry for the bad cuality. I just formated the nvme drive to see if i can install ubuntu 20.04 LTS in the whole drive

Comment: Sorry, I can't decipher this without a translation.